# A Hovering cursor over an image html 1

Tags: html, css

So my question is, that if i insert an image (lets say an image of a dog) , and if i hover my cursor over the image, a dog barking sound effect starts to play. I wrote down a code, now i hope this is right.

I need this assignment for my school project  in the UK, the problem is that the sound effect wont start to play, if i hover my cursor over it. :((

index:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Háziállatok</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <center><h1><u>Háziállatok</u></h1></center>
    <a href="#" class="active">Kezdőoldal</a>
    <a href="aszerzorol.html">A szerzőről</a>
    <a href="utasitas.html">Használati utasítás</a>
    <div id="main">
        <br />
        A hang lejátszásának engedélyezéséhez felhasználói interakció szükséges az oldalon belül (pl. kattintás).
        <br />
        <br />
        <img src="images/dog.jpg" alt="dog" />
        <img src="images/rabbit.jpg" alt="rabbit" />
        <img src="images/parrot.jpg" alt="parrot" />
        <img src="images/cat.jpg" alt="cat" />
        <img src="images/hamster.jpg" alt="hamster" />
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Of the author:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Háziállatok</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <center><h1><u>A szerzőről</u></h1></center>
    <a href="index.html">Kezdőoldal</a>
    <a href="#" class="active">A szerzőről</a>
    <a href="utasitas.html">Használati utasítás</a>
    <div id="main">
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        Name <br>
        Class <br><br>
        
        <br />
        <br />

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

How to use it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Háziállatok</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <center><h1><u>Használati utasítás</u></h1></center>
    <a href="index.html">Kezdőoldal</a>
    <a href="aszerzorol.html">A szerzőről</a>
    <a href="#" class="active">Használati utasítás</a>
    <div id="main">
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        A főoldalon a képek fölé húzva az egeret hallhatjuk az állat hangját. <br>
        A képekre kattintva a képen szereplő állat rövid leírását olvashatjuk a kiugró ablakban.
        <br />
        <br />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript code:

```
var images = [].slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName('img')),
    data = {
        desc: {
            dog: 'Ez egy kutyuli leiras.',
            cat: 'Ez egy cica leiras.',
            parrot: 'Ez egy papagaj leiras.',
            hamster: 'Ez egy csinos patkany leiras.',
            rabbit: 'Ez egy nyul leiras.'
        },
        sounds: {
            dog: new Audio('sounds/dog.wav'),
            cat: new Audio('sounds/cat.wav'),
            parrot: new Audio('sounds/parrot.wav'),
            hamster: new Audio('sounds/hamster.wav'),
            rabbit: new Audio('sounds/rabbit.wav')
        }
    },
    current_sound = '';

for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    images[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
        showPopup(data.desc[this.alt]);
    });
    images[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
        if (current_sound != '') data.sounds[current_sound].pause();
        data.sounds[this.alt].currentTime = 0;
        data.sounds[this.alt].play();
        current_sound = this.alt;
    });
}
function showPopup(s) {
    popup = window.open("", "", "asdf");
    popup.document.write(s);
}
```

Style code:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
h1 {
    padding: 20px 0;
}
#main {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100vh;
    background: url('../images/background.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% auto;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    padding: 10px;
    float: left;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
    cursor: pointer;
    border-right: 1px solid #999;
}
.active {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
#main {
    text-align: center;
}
#main > img {
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: I'm assuming you have some javascript to do this, where is the javascript?

Comment: Yes, i just edited it!

Comment: you don't seem to be referencing the js from the html anywhere, is this all the relevant code?

Comment: This would it be all. I got the 3 HTML's the Js and the style (css) code, and of course a folder of the pictures of the animals, and their sound effect

Comment: you'll need something like `<script src="myscripts.js"></script>` in `head`